transferring money between two players with game
Suppose there is a 2 player betting game. The total EV of the game, between the two players is say, $H$, where $H\leq 1$. player 1 and player 2 together choose their probability of winning. the probability of player 1 winning, $p(w1)$ is equal to $1-p(w2)$ where $p(w2)$ is the probability of player 2 winning and the payout for winning is $1/p(\text{respective player wins})\cdot H\cdot \text{wager}$. Is there a strategy where player 1 is able to shift their balance to player 2, on average, but also minimizing the total lost between the two players? (if this helps, we can imagine that player 1 has infinite money).
I have a feeling that this is not possible but I wonder if there is a proof. If it isnt possible, what conditions would make it that this may be possible?
One idea that I had was that you could play a martingale-ish strategy as follows: set the win rate of p1 as low as possible, say $p(w1)=a<<1$. then start with player 2 wagering $1$ dollar, p1 wagering $1/a$ dollars. if player 2 wins, reset to $1$. If p1 wins, p2 wagers $2$, then 4, etc. This strategy clearly fails; it seems like looking at just player 2s balance, you cant even tell player 1 is involved at all. player 2 is just martingale'ing. if you only had a certain amount of balance you wanted to move, this strategy seems ok, the probability of p2 winning seems higher than say, a 50 50 wager with constant bet sizes.
